# CICD Pipeline Filed Python, Unit Testing TypeError: missing positional argument

Tags: python, unit-testing, cicd

Hello guys good afternoon, I hope everything is going well.

I have a project and of course locally works amazing without any problem. The issues comes when I push to GitLab and the CICD test_job doesn't pass so never is build.

Basically the problem is the test part.

The project has a `conftest.py` file that has some functions, like this:

```
def app(client_app):
    f = partial(TestClient, client_app)
    yield f
```

And the project has unit testing files, one example is like this:

```
import unittest

class MyTestApplicationTopic(unittest.TestCase):

    URL = "/someUrl"
    data_app_topic = {
        "topic": "burning",
        "topic_remarks": "burning",
        "application_id": 1
    }



    def test_connection(self, app):
        with app() as client:
            response = client.get(self.URL)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
            print('test passed')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tester = MyTestApplicationTopic()
    tester.test_connection()
```

So basically as you see it's a normal unit test.

As you see the `app()` function from `conftest.py` is passed to the `test_connection(self, app)` function as argument

Of course this is not going to work because when I initialized the class I don't pass the argument:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tester = MyTestApplicationTopic()
    tester.test_connection()
```

The thing is that I don't know how to pass the argument because as I mentioned before, the `tes_conecction(self, app)` function, takes this argument from the conftest.py.

So, Obviusly I get the error:

`'TypeError: test_connection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'`

So basically is something confuse for me because I need to pass the app from conftest.py because this is something related with the project configuration so bascially I pass app() function as argument but also the app()function takes another fucntios as argument and that fucntion takes another function as argument and so on and so for.

So at the end I don't know how handle the error: `'TypeError: test_connection() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'` in this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conftest.py` seems to be for pytest, not unittest. Since pytest can run unittest tests, you can run tests with Pytest and put the fixture decorator on `app`:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def app(client_app):
    f = partial(TestClient, client_app)
    yield f
```

With pytest, you don't need the if main, just run `pytest` and the framework will run tests for you while injecting fixture when needed.

```bash
path/to/project$ pytest
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your advise was really helpful, the issue with the argument missing is solved. Now I'm facing another error related with another thing, still don't pass the CICD pipe line test_job, but is another thing is not related with the issue that I asked in this post.

Thanks for your help.